# Show git versions in php explorer

Tags: php, eclipse, git, version

I'm using Eclipse 4.3 Kepler and I have Egit installed. 
I want to display current project versions in my php explore but for now I can only see them in the Git Repositories view.

How to display version next to the project's name ?
I saw it before but I can't make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get EGit to "know" that your project is a Git project is for it to import it using its import project wizard.  Here are the steps:

1. Delete your existing project from Eclipse package/project explorer (don't delete the contents of course)
2. Go to `EGit repositories view` and select the directory of your project in the working directory tree
3. Right click the project folder and choose `import projects...` action.
4. Select your existing project and import

Now when the project is opened in Eclipse it will have the EGit decorations that show the repo, branch, status, etc.

Comment: Thanks ! that's exactly it !